# Extracting digits after certain characters that appear more than once from a string field in Hive

Tags: regex, hiveql, regexp-replace

I'm trying to extract all digits that appear after 'dd ->'

I've figured out how to extract first occurence of digits after 'dd ->': `regexp_extract(string, 'dd\\s->\\s([0-9]+)')`
and how to replace all characters except digits
`regexp_replace(string, '[^0-9]+', '')` but failed to find a solution

String:
`(dd -> 2192, bar -> 1), (dd -> 2670, bar -> 1), (dd -> 2487, bar -> 3),(dd -> 2346, bar -> 3) kk=67457 ghyt=1628 nn=8.67.1`

Desired output:
`2192 2670 2487 2346`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```js
dd ->( [0-9]+)|.
```

**Replace with** `$1`.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ZIEjzK/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  dd ->                    'dd ->'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .                        any character except \n
```

Trim the first space if needed.